# What is the male-female balance on different Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, statistics

I was concerned to learn that the [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) has historically had about [15% of edits contributed by females](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_bias_on_Wikipedia).

> the difference in contribution rates could be due to three factors: (1) the high levels of conflict in discussions, (2) dislike of critical environments (i.e. without reading the wiki reference, people downvote me 16 times: it's an example of a critical environment), and (3) lack of confidence in editing other contributors' work.([4 references given](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_bias_on_Wikipedia#Causes_of_gender_bias_in_participation))

This made me wonder if that applies to the Stack Exchange network as well.

Do we have any figures for the male/female contribution and statistics for the various sites, i.e. *[Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour)*, *[Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour)*, [programming](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), *[Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour)*, and *[Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour)*?

Comment: As you can see, there's no info, because gender is not required for user sign up (which is a good thing)

Comment: Most of the contributors are called mark.

Comment: @aliential I know right, it is strange how many Marks are on here :)

Comment: You can have a look at the developer survey to have a grasp of this ratio.

Comment: @Luuklag That’s not a good gauge of sites other than SO. That survey is very targeted to a large but narrow section of the people participating in SE.

Comment: @ColleenV in addition, any survey where users can enter at will is inherently vulnerable to [self-selection bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-selection_bias). So, all we can say is that *from the people who answered the survey*, X% are (for example) male. That doesn't need to coincide with the actual percentage of SO users. It's much less an indicator of what the userbase is on, for example, Biology.SE or Chemistry.SE, etc.

Comment: Why do you need these numbers? And what do they have to do with Wikipedia?

Comment: @aliential Why do you think gender has any correlation with how someone deals with an argumentative tone? As a woman and an engineer, and having helped drive the rest of my family from the room on more than one occasion when my father and I were debating a point, I think you’re barking up the wrong tree. Out of curiosity, are you not interrogating the non-female rioters, or do you think data doesn’t work well on them? ;)

Comment: There's the Developer Survey: https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#developer-profile-_-gender and https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/07/27/public-data-release-of-stack-overflows-2020-developer-survey/

Comment: @ColleenV because I don't speak myth off the top of my head for the sake of it... Quoting the link you didn't read:  Some gender research literature suggests that the difference in contribution rates could be due to three factors: (1) the high levels of conflict in discussions, (2) dislike of critical environments, and (3) lack of confidence in editing other contributors' work. it's on the second link included in the OP.

Comment: @aliential how is getting the numbers on male/female contribution related to those 3 things you keep quoting? You can't just say that once you have the actual numbers, you can directly say they're caused by those same 3 things, so what do you need the actual numbers for? What do those numbers have to do with Wikipedia?

Comment: @aliential If you find that the numbers on the Stack Exchange network exactly match global population statistics for people who identify as women online, what conclusion will you draw? How can you draw any conclusion without also getting measurements of discussion conflict on each site, the respondents' lack of confidence in their edits and dislike of critical environments? The numbers don't tell you anything meaningful by themselves.

Comment: You mean, if reddit has 55 percent female english speakers and stack has 21%, the numers dont tell anything meaningful in themselves? I guess we won't know because we don't have the numbers!

Comment: @aliential The fact that you think those percentages should mean something without more context is an indication that you will draw the wrong conclusion from them no matter what they turn out to be. Does it mean something if the typical English translation of the Christian Bible has 32% more instances of the word "woman" than the typical English translation of the Quran. Why does it mention women more? Are the translators biased? Is mentioning women more often bad or good? The numbers don't tell us anything except that the discrepancy exists.

Comment: Somewhat similar question on Meta StackOverflow: [Measuring the participation of women on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290727).

Comment: @aliential I’m not offended, I’m just trying to help you understand that scientific inquiry is more than statistics. You’re the one getting emotional. It seems that further discussion is going to be fruitless. This [article on how to read research papers as a layperson](https://www.wikihow.com/Read-a-Scientific-Paper) might be helpful. Forbes is not a peer-reviewed scientific journal. If you want to know whether a conclusion is likely to be true, you need to read the research, not some journalist’s or crowd-sourced summary of it.

Answer (score 15):

No one *really* knows.

Outside the 'core', fairly engaged userbase - SE's pretty much an asocial network, with our systems designed to not really collect demographic or personal information. Content was our main concern.

While SE does do surveys and tries to work out/address the gender gap, this has *entirely* been focused on SO and developers, and at least one major change in web site design was initially attributed to making it easier for women to engage. This is a blind spot I hope they realise they have and address some day ;).

There's also folks who might be something other than male or female - and if we're counting folks by gender, its worth considering everybody, no matter how they identify themselves.

Most of these surveys also tend to be fairly random and as much for the 'casual user' as the core - and to me, reaching out to and building on the *core* engaged userbase - which would *include* making sure that barriers to active participation are removed is essential.

So - we don't know. At the moment the company doesn't *quite* have it on the roadmap from the perspective of moderators like myself.

Comment: "*moderators like myself*" which brings us to another point - as can be clearly seen from your profile picture a dog wearing the moderator hat. We don't even have accurate data on the human/non-human balance on the network. There are blurry flowers and who knows what else using the sites.

Comment: Meta has no human mods right now. Just 2 dogs and a parrot . More seriously, it's probably easier to poll this data for mods ( and there's likely more variation than the gender binary) than it is to get an accurate view of a broader community, especially if you are not looking.

Comment: At least I didn't lie when I checked the 'I am not a robot' checkbox! Looking at aibobot :P

Answer (score -8):

The other answer states that "No-one *really* knows". But that doesn't mean no basis exists for an estimate that's worth communicating. It does not seem equally likely that 90% of contributors here are female as that 50% are, or 10%.

Going by the behaviour here, and also by the [data that indicates that more than 90% of software developers are male](https://www.statista.com/statistics/1126823/worldwide-developer-gender/), I'd guess that

### more than 90% of contributions here are by males.

Comment: That's just a wild guess, and while it might be true, it might as well be false.

Comment: What do you reckon then? Would you be OK with saying that an estimate of over 80% male is safe at a 95% confidence level?

Comment: Perhaps downvoters and upvoters could identify their gender in the comments? :-)

Comment: I'm going to say your basic premise of assuming that everyone that participates on any site in the Stack Exchange network is a software developer is wrong, and as such your extrapolation is even more wrong.

Comment: "Everyone" wasn't a basic premise. Will you make your own guess as to the percentage? For example, would you care to assert with 95% confidence that more than 55% of contributors are male - or would the basis even for such an obviously true statement be too flimsy for such public "wildness"?

Comment: @ruffle we can compare it to a question asking "What is the percentage of people, in the whole world, who wear a blue shirt today?" - there's no way to know, and any guess will be just a wild guess.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating Today is white shirt day, not blue shirt day :) https://www.daysoftheyear.com/days/white-shirt-day/

Comment: @sam I wear white shirts every day. ;)

Comment: @Shadow - You make the point that we can't know exactly and for certain. But so what? The question about the blue shirts is reasonable and a sensible estimate could be arrived at. Some employers ask interview questions like that...including sometimes of software developers.

Comment: @shadow The important thing is to not wear red (or yellow) https://digg.com/2019/star-trek-shirt-color-death-data-viz

Comment: @sam OMG, hope underwear don't count towards that rate. :P

Comment: Silly me. I should have typed "_It DOES seem equally likely that 90% of contributors here are female as that 50% are, or 10%._" After all, nobody can "prove" to the contrary, the way they might be able to prove that 7 is not an element of the set {1,2,3}.